# Test.QuickCheck.Monadic: why is assert applied to Bool, not Testable a => a

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

In [*Testing Monadic Code with QuickCheck* (Claessen, Hughes 2002)](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=636527), `assert` has the type:

```
assert :: (Monad m, Testable a) => a -> PropertyM m ()
```

However, in [**`Test.QuickCheck.Monadic`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.1.0.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Monadic.html#v:assert), it has the type:

```
assert :: (Monad m) => Bool -> PropertyM m ()
```

Why does `assert` have the latter type in the library?

Comment: Perhaps the comments in the source will be of some help: [(link)](https://github.com/nick8325/quickcheck/blob/master/Test/QuickCheck/Monadic.hs#L118-126). Interesting that the comment for `assert` has the paper's sig, and also `stop` basically has the same sig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it was due to technical constraints, because currently to evaluate a `Testable` with the `Test.QuickCheck` library, you need to use one of the [`quickCheck*`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:quickCheckWith) functions, which are very `IO`-centric. That happens because QuickCheck tests `Testable` properties by randomly generating possible inputs (by default 100), trying to find a [counterexample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexample) which proves the property false. If such input is not found, the property is assumed to be true (although that is not necessarily the truth; there may be a counterexample that was not tested). And to be able to generate random inputs in Haskell, we are stuck to the `IO` monad.

Notice that even though `assert` was defined in such a generic way, it is used through all the paper only with `Bool`. So the library author (the same of the paper) preferred to sacrifice the generic `Testable` parameter for a simple `Bool`, to not force any monad at this point.

And we can see that they have even written the original signature as a comment in the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.1/docs/src/Test-QuickCheck-Monadic.html#line-122):

```
-- assert :: Testable prop => prop -> PropertyM m ()
```

Also note that despite the fact that `stop` function has a similar signature:

```
stop :: (Testable prop, Monad m) => prop -> PropertyM m a
```

It is **not** the same as the `assert` function in the paper, as the former will **stop** the computation in both cases either the condition is `True` or `False`. On the other hand, `assert` will only stop the computation if the condition is `False`:

> ⟦ assert True ≫ p ⟧ = ⟦ p ⟧
>
> ⟦ assert False ≫ p ⟧ = { return False }

We can though easily write a `IO` version of the `assert` function from the paper:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Monadic
import Test.QuickCheck.Property
import Test.QuickCheck.Test

assertIO :: Testable prop => prop -> PropertyM IO ()
assertIO p = do r <- liftIO $ quickCheckWithResult stdArgs{chatty = False} p
                unless (isSuccess r) $ fail "Assertion failed"
```

And now we can make a test to see the differences between `assertIO` and `stop`:

```
prop_assert :: Property
prop_assert = monadicIO $ do assertIO succeeded
                             assertIO failed

prop_stop :: Property
prop_stop = monadicIO $ do stop succeeded
                           stop failed

main :: IO ()
main = do putStrLn "prop_assert:"
          quickCheck prop_assert
          putStrLn "prop_stop:"
          quickCheck prop_stop
```

The `succeeded` and `failed` could be replaced by `True` and `False`, respectively. It was just to show that now we are not limited to `Bool`, instead we can use any `Testable`.

And the output is:

> prop_assert:
>   *** Failed! Assertion failed (after 1 test):
>   prop_stop:
>   +++ OK, passed 100 tests.

As we can see, despite the fact that the first `assertIO` succeeded, `prop_assert` failed due to the second `assertIO`. On the other hand, `prop_stop` passed the test, because the first `stop` succeeded and the computation has stopped at that point, not testing the second `stop`.

Comment: But what is the reason that the `quickCheck*` functions "are very IO-centric", if it leads to giving up some of the generality in the library as proposed by the paper.

Comment: @frasertweedale The problem is that QuickCheck tests `Testable` properties by randomly generating possible inputs (by default 100), trying to find a [counterexample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexample) which proves the property false. If such input is not found, the property is assumed true (although that is not necessarily the truth; there may be a counterexample that was not tested). And to be able to generate random inputs in Haskell, we are stuck to the `IO` monad. Note also that even if `assert` was defined in such generic way, it is used through all the paper only with `Bool`.

Comment: Ok, is is starting to become a bit clearer.. the above points would be good to include in your answer.